# Store date and time from Java in SQL SERVER

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I am trying to store datetime from Java using GregorianCalendar class in SQL SERVER, however it only stores date. I need to store the date and time in SQL SERVER.

this is the code i implemented

```
CallableStatement asignarTurno=conexionBBDD
                .getConexionBBDD().prepareCall("{call asignarTurno(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
                
                //GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)
                
                GregorianCalendar h=new GregorianCalendar(2000, 1, 1, 8, 30,0);
                
                java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(h.getTimeInMillis());
                 
                
                asignarTurno.setInt(1,1);
                asignarTurno.setDate(2,date);
                asignarTurno.setDate(3,date);
                asignarTurno.setDate(4,date);
                asignarTurno.setString(5, "000");
                asignarTurno.setString(6,"0001");
  
                
                asignarTurno.execute();
                
                  
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the columns?

Comment: the data type of the columns is Date

Comment: Post details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: @AriPaez Change to datetime. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 The datatype date can only store the date part

Comment: BTW. Do not longer use the outdated Calendar-API. Use the modern `java.time` -API

Answer (score 2):

Multiple problems with your code.

Never use the terrible date-time classes such as `GregorianCalendar` and `Date`. These were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

You are trying to represent a moment having a date, a time-of-day, and an implicit time zone (`GregorianCalendar`) into a data type that pretends to hold only a date (`java.sql.Date`). Square peg, round hole.

## Date-only

The [`DATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) type in Microsoft SQL Server is akin to the SQL-standard type `DATE`, holding only a date, without a time-of-day, and without a time zone. So use `java.time.LocalDate` in Java.

```java
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2000 , Month.FEBRUARY , 1 ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```java
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

## Moment

If you do indeed want to track moments, you must redefine your database column with an appropriate [data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type). In standard SQL, that would be `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In Microsoft SQL Server, that would be [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

In Java, you would place your date at time-of-day in the context of a time zone. This produces a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```java
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2000 , Month.FEBRUARY , 1 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of ( 8 , 30 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

Unfortunately, the [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 team inexplicably decided to require support for `OffsetDateTime` but not the two more commonly-used classes, `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime`. So for maximum portable code, use `OffsetDateTime`. If portability is not so important, test your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) to see if it optionally chose to support `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant`.

We could just call `ZonedDateTime#toOffsetDateTime`. But this would bring the offset used by that time zone at that moment. For clarity, I suggest instead adjusting to UTC. That is easily accomplished by extracting a [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) (always in UTC) from our [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Then we convert to [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) with an [offset of zero](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC), per JDBC 4.2 spec.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toInstant().atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Then pass to your prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).